# Installing pip for Python 3.4 - Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pip, osx-mavericks

as you know the Mac comes with Python pre-installed, mine has the 2.7 version. I installed Python 3.4. I installed **pip** using the command 
    **sudo easy_install** 
however it gets installed to the 2.7 version of Python and all the packages i download therefore get installed to the 2.7 version.
Is there a way to install pip to the Python 3.4 version?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: How did you install python3? You should have `easy_install-3.4` too somewhere. If you install pip using that, it will work for Python3.

Comment: you should avoid changing the python version on a mac because the OS uses it - if you switch from 2.x-3.x some stuff will likely break.

Comment: Yes it had easy_install-3.4, thank you! It installed at the 3.4 version.

Answer (score 9):

I installed Python 3.4 for my Mac from this page:

https://www.python.org/download/

It installed pip automatically, but it's called `pip3`, not `pip`. Type `which pip3` at the console to find it.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not averse to using a third-party package manager, the easiest way I've found to deal with 3.x on OS X is to use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/). You can [maintain custom 2.x and 3.x installations](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Homebrew-and-Python) (with `pip` and `pip3` and everything else) alongside the system 2.7 installation with no problems.